# Play store and Google play markets ratings on webpage

Tags: android, google-play

My friend made application for iOS and Android and added it to play store and google play. I would like to make website to promote them, but I wonder how to add ratings from those stores on our website. I couldn't find anything on the web so my first approach is to parse website from this store and copy ratings from their source codes. This would be so slow. Anyone has an idea how to make it faster?

Comment: How slow is "slow"? Have you tried it, and if so, which aspect of the approach is the bottleneck?

Comment: The bottleneck is getting source code of webpage and what if someone has turned off javascript? I can parse it in the server side, but better sollution would be to get json with some of current app data from the store, but i couldn't find anything about that. Also i tought about run script everyday to parse it and save in the database, but those ratings may change during the day.